# mmap() and munmap()

Tags: unix, memory-management, shared-memory, virtual-memory

`mmap()` creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process starting at `addr` and `len` bytes and `munmap()` removes any mappings for those entire pages containing any part of the address space of the process starting at `addr` and continuing for `len` bytes.

I want to ask if the modified mmap files are written to disk by the munmap before releasing the memory or we have to call a different function to sync the modification.

Comment: On what operating system? What flags are you passing to `mmap`? What do you mean by “mmap files” and “munmap file”?

Comment: Unix operating system. mmap files means the data written to the mapped memory. If data are loaded into memory mapped and then some modification are performed on that. Parmeters provided are mmap(
NULL, size, readOnly ? PROT_READ : PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0).

Comment: The problem with your question is that mmap is a jack-of-all trades function. The behavior depends upon how you actually all it. You should be more specific as to what settings you are using in your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `mmap()` with the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag, your changes will never be saved.  If you use the `MAP_SHARED` flag, your changes will be saved without additional calls at some indeterminate time but before `munmap()` returns.  And you can force the changes to be written to the file by using the `msync()` call.

Per [the POSIX standard for `mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> ***DESCRIPTION***
>
> ...
>
> MAP_SHARED and MAP_PRIVATE describe the disposition of write
>   references to the memory object. If MAP_SHARED is specified, write
>   references shall change the underlying object. If MAP_PRIVATE is
>   specified, modifications to the mapped data by the calling process
>   shall be visible only to the calling process and shall not change the
>   underlying object. ...
>
> ...
>
> The last data access timestamp of the mapped file may be marked for
>   update at any time between the `mmap()` call and the corresponding
>   `munmap()` call. The initial read or write reference to a mapped region
>   shall cause the file's last data access timestamp to be marked for
>   update if it has not already been marked for update.
>
> The last data modification and last file status change timestamps of a
>   file that is mapped with MAP_SHARED and PROT_WRITE shall be marked for
>   update at some point in the interval between a write reference to the
>   mapped region and the next call to `msync()` with MS_ASYNC or MS_SYNC
>   for that portion of the file by any process. If there is no such call
>   and if the underlying file is modified as a result of a write
>   reference, then these timestamps shall be marked for update at some
>   time after the write reference.

And per [the `munmap()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/munmap.html):

> ***DESCRIPTION***
>
> ...
>
> If a mapping to be removed was private, any modifications made in this
>   address range shall be discarded.

Comment: I am sorry Andrew, but I do not see any phrase here that confirms your statement "your changes will be saved without additional calls at some indeterminate time but before munmap() returns". Could you, please, point out to me?